# Third monitor setup problems

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two screens, one HDMI and one VGA, pluged into my main graphics card which is a Radeon 7800. I have a second graphics card installed which is a pretty old NVIDIA. However, when I plug a VGA monitor into the NVIDIA it doesn't show up. 
I am entirrely sure the card works because if I remove the VGA from the Radeon the third(NVIDIA VGA) monitor works and I can use it then. If I remove the HDMI from my Radeon it the second and third also work. - All three monitors(and the two GPU's) are detected by Windows's Device Manager. -
I would like to have three monitors. No SLI of CrossFire is wanted, I just want three screens.
I am running Windows 10.

Question:
How do I enable three monitors at the same time from two different GPU's.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't connect all three monitors to the Radeon? It's much less likely to cause any driver conflicts or trouble. You may need an adaptor from eg. DP to VGA or DVI, but these are fairly cheap.

Comment: Like @Vojtech said, you should really be using 1 card for all 3 monitors. Hell, I do it without issue.

Comment: The reason why is that I have the extra GPU but don't really want to spend 10 - 20 euros. I understand that that is an option(although I've read that GPU's most of the time don't want to output more than 2 monitors), but I'd really like if this could work and somebody could help me.
And another reason would be that if my Radeon fails I'm not in that big of a problem because my other GPU would still work and I'd be able to repair it more easily.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for certain, but I believe for three monitors they all need to be on one graphics card.

Looking at a [Specs Sheet](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/7000/7800) it looks like those cards come with the following ports:

HDMI
Dual-Link DVI
VGA
Display Port

However the one below from a Google Image search shows different.

[image]

This 7800 only has DVI, HDMI, and 2 display ports, so it varies between manufacturer on what ports are available.

If you have a display port, why not use a [Display Port to VGA Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0025ZUF8K)?

Note:

Just test on my office computer, that has a Geforce 650TI (has two DVI, 1 HDMI, 1 Display Port), and added in a Geforce 620, and couldn't get three monitors to run in the same setup you were trying.  This computer is Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I have seen many setups for many more than three monitors and this is achieved through multiple video cards

Comment: Display Port to *VGA*? Well; you'd lose all the advantages of all-digital connections. Since modern monitors are fully digital, you are introducing two analog/digital conversion steps where there needs to be none. (First to get from DP to VGA, then from VGA to whatever the monitor uses natively.) This *will* lead to a degradation of image quality.